# Form a vector A of length 100 whose odd and even position value will be 2 and 3, respectively

Tags: r

I would like to form a vector A of length 100 whose odd and even position value will be  2 and 3, respectively, without using loop or replacing procedure.

```
A<- rep(0, 100)
A[seq(2,10, 2)] = 3
A[seq(1,10, 2)] = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `rep` function you used initially:

```
A <- rep(2:3, 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ifelse(seq_along(A) %% 2 == 1, 2, 3)

  [1] 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
 [59] 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2x50 matrix with the first row being 2s and the second row being 3s. Then cast it as a vector.

```
c(rbind(rep(2, 50), rep(3, 50)))
[1] 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
[91] 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3
```

Comment: A similar option : `c(2, 3)[rep(c(1, 2), 50)]`

Answer (score 0):

To simplify [ifelse solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59156738/680068):

```
3 - (seq_along(A) %% 2)
```

or using recycling:

```
A[ c(TRUE, FALSE) ] <- 2
A[ c(FALSE, TRUE) ] <- 3
```